# how to display image from database using php and mysql in a html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

This is my php and  mysql retrive code

```
<?php
    include_once("config.php");
    $image_id = $_GET['image_id'];

    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM image WHERE image_id = $image_id");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    $image=$row['path_txt'];
    //echo $image;
    $path ="<img src='http://localhost:8080/memes/".$image."' />";
    echo $path;

    }
   ?>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<html> <head> </head> <body> <img src=urlencode("sample.php?image_id=58")/> <img src="<?php include("sample.php?image_id=58");?>"/> <?php echo "<img src= 'localhost:8080/memes/sample.php?image_id=58'/>";; echo "<a href =urlencode("/sample.php?image_id=58")>"; ?> </body> </html>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src=urlencode("sample.php?image_id=58")/>


<img src="<?php include("sample.php?image_id=58");?>"/>
<?php
echo "<img src= 'http://localhost:8080/memes/sample.php?image_id=58'/>";
echo "<a href =urlencode("/sample.php?image_id=58")>";        


?>
</body>
</html>
its my html code

Comment: what error or notice you get while executing the code

Comment: Is this a question?  Could you edit, explain what is expected, what is happening (not as expected) and include your output please.

Comment: why not use Smarty Templates? assign the path out og the database to a variable and use it in the presentation layer? easier done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better if you create a function for get image source and then use. Like below.

functions.php

```
<?php
  function getImgSrc ($image_id) { 
     $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM image WHERE image_id = $image_id LIMIT 0, 1");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); 
     $image=$row['path_txt'];
     //echo $image;
     $path ="<img src='http://localhost:8080/memes/".$image."' />";
     return $path;

}
```

In index.php where you need to display that image.

```
<?php 
  // include functions.php
  include 'functions.php';  
?>
 <img src="<?php echo getImgSrc(58); ?>"/>
```

Comment: in case that `$image_id` comes from the user, you might want to sanitize it, using at least `$image_id = intval($image_id)` before putting it to query.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$image' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xamppp\htdocs\memes\sample.php on line 6

Comment: Replace this line 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)
with 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

Comment: I have modified functions.php to fix error please latest code.

Comment: it's better not to intermix HTML and database interaction. The function should return the path only. Besides, this function will fail because $musqli is undefined.

Comment: image is not displaying some call function is not working

Comment: <?php
  function getImgSrc ($image_id) { 
     $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM image WHERE image_id = $image_id LIMIT 0, 1");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); 
     $image=$row['path_txt'];
     //echo $image;
     $path ="<img src='http://localhost:8080/memes/".$image."' />";
     return $path;

}
?>

Comment: `<?php
  function getImgSrc ($image_id) { 
     $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM image WHERE image_id = $image_id LIMIT 0, 1");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); 
     $image=$row['path_txt'];
     //echo $image;
     $path ="<img src='http://localhost:8080/memes/".$image."' />";
     return $path;

}
?>`

Comment: `<?php 

  include 'sample.php';  
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="<?php echo getImgSrc(58); ?>"/>



</body>
</html>`

Comment: Functions seems to working fine but function for database results. Make sure data is coming properly.